# Summarize size of folders in Ubuntu on command line

Tags: ubuntu, command, command-line-interface, du

I am trying to get the combined size of all folders i select with a wildcard. 
At the moment I get a sorted list with all the "compressed" folders. 
I use the following command:

```
du -sh /var/www/*/web/typo3temp/assets/compressed/ | sort -h
```

Is there a way to get a "sum" at the end?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, its just -c

```
du -shc /var/www/*/web/typo3temp/assets/compressed/ | sort -h
```

gives me a nice combined size!